# Filling form with list items with line break after each list item

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium/Python and I'm pretty new at programming. I couldn't find a solution anywhere for my case.

I'm trying to fill a form on a webpage with the content of a list of strings, using .send_keys. The form requires each item to be separated by a line break, like so:

```
    item1
    item2
    item3
    item4
    item5
```

I have the following list : `items_list = [item1, item2, item4, item5]`

So I tried the following loop:

```
for it in items_list:
    driver.find_element_by_id("WHATEVER ID").send_keys(items_list)
```

As a result the form is filled without line break:

```
    item1item2item3item4item5
```

I tried using `items_list2 = '\n'.join(items_list)` without success: I get

```
    i
    t
    e
    m
    1
    i
    t
    e
    m
    2
    ...and so on
```

Since I'm learning Python as I code I must have missed something but I'm not sure of what I should be looking for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know how the internals of `send_keys` works but seems like using a loop and sending the items one at a time in to the form might work

Comment: Why should a _WebElement_ i.e. `driver.find_element_by_id()` take a **line** separated text? This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure the text filed you are trying `Multi-line` text field NOT `single-line`?

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm a newbie, I wasn't sure how to present my issue clearly enough. I edited it and added an answer with the solution I found

Answer (score 0):

```
items_list = '\n'.join([item1, item2, item4, item5])
item_list = item_list.replace("\n", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER))
driver.find_element_by_id("WHATEVER ID").send_keys(items_list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thank you all, I actually found the solution to my issue. I thought that simply passing "\n" after each list item would be a string, like so:

`item1\nitem2\nitem3\nitem4\nitem5\n`

But it actually added a line break to the form:

```
for it in items_list:
    driver.find_element_by_id("WHATEVER ID").send_keys(items_list)
    driver.find_element_by_id("WHATEVER ID").send_keys("\n")
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
```